# Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process in python

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIEhl.png)Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process in python
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process

Comment: First explain briefly what is your problem and what you tried. finally add your error message.

Comment: Hi, and welcome. Please add part of your code so that we can understand what causes the error

Comment: Hm, python3.6.. there is newer version there, also selenium-wire can be tried as option

Answer (score 0):

The message says that the process already exited, so it can´t be killed, but without your code, i can´t figure out whats happening.

¿Maybe your driver is outdated?

Comment: driver is newest